# Esp8266 -12E v3

Tags: esp8266

So I have this ESP 8266 v3 board that has a program. Running on it currently, it’s the example scan Network Program. No matter what program I send to it now I get a error complaining for board NodeMCU 1.0 (ESP-12E).
I have checked to assure that the com port is correct and is showing upload 11500 , cpu 80 MHz, flash size 4M, debug disabled. Debug level - none, iwip v2 low memory 
Viable”flash”, exception enable, erase flash only sketch 
Port 6 . 
   Arduino 1.8.8 Windows 10
In error box print in red

```
Board nodemcuv2. (platform, esp8266, package edp8266 is Unknown. 
Error compiling for board NodeMCU 1.0 (ESP-12E Module)
```

Used this board a few times without an issue, now no matter what I try it maintains the current scan program and I am unanticipated compile or upload to the board. Is it stuck in some sort of loop or what? Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: Sorry for typos here, should read I am unable to compile or upload any program. I tried and when I opened the serial window it showed my network being scanned. Thanks

Comment: go to Board Manager in IDE and reinstall the esp8266 boards package

Comment: why are you posting a comment about the typos, instead of correcting the typos?

Comment: `I am unable to compile` - then the issue is not with the hardware ... `package edp8266 is Unknown` ... what is this package *edp8266* - looks like an obvious typo, but is that typo yours (i.e. you typed it wrong here) or is that the actual message you are getting